# For which values of a is this quadratic function convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

The function is
$$f(x; y; z) = 2x^2 + (x + y)^2 + (x + z)^2 + 2ayz.$$
I have seen that it's convex if the associated matrix is semi-definite, but then I don't know how to demonstrate if it's semi-definite. I have tried to find the eigenvalues to see if they are all equal or greater then 0, but I can't find them by hand.
Do you have any suggestions?
thank you for your time

Comment: Show us your try. Hint: collect like terms and use $\det{A-\lambda I}$ to find the eigenvalues.

Comment: How can I show it? The calculations get ugly. Aren't there other ways other than the determinant? or other ways to demonstrate the convexity other than seeing if the matrix is positive semidefinite?

Comment: we may use Sylvester's Law of Inertia; I wrote about  finding $P^T H P = D$ for given symmetric $H$, and the $D$ is diagonal and constructed by the method.          http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr